# Random 403 Forbidden error (Apache 2.4)

Tags: linux, php, apache-2.4

My Apache 2.4 (CentOS 7) server hosts multiple websites. Sometimes I get a 403 Forbidden (You don't have permission to access file X on this server) error when accessing any of the websites files (mostly php scripts). Hitting F5 for a few seconds will resolve it and load the page normally. The files have correct permissions. I also got mod_evasive enabled but the log does not show any IP being blocked at that time.

```
 Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 cloudflare_module (shared)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 allowmethods_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 auth_digest_module (shared)
 authn_anon_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_dbd_module (shared)
 authn_dbm_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authn_socache_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_dbd_module (shared)
 authz_dbm_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_owner_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cache_module (shared)
 cache_disk_module (shared)
 data_module (shared)
 dbd_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 dumpio_module (shared)
 echo_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 ext_filter_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 include_module (shared)
 info_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 logio_module (shared)
 mime_magic_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 remoteip_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 slotmem_plain_module (shared)
 slotmem_shm_module (shared)
 socache_dbm_module (shared)
 socache_memcache_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 substitute_module (shared)
 suexec_module (shared)
 unique_id_module (shared)
 unixd_module (shared)
 userdir_module (shared)
 version_module (shared)
 vhost_alias_module (shared)
 dav_module (shared)
 dav_fs_module (shared)
 dav_lock_module (shared)
 lua_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bybusyness_module (shared)
 lbmethod_byrequests_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bytraffic_module (shared)
 lbmethod_heartbeat_module (shared)
 proxy_ajp_module (shared)
 proxy_balancer_module (shared)
 proxy_connect_module (shared)
 proxy_express_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 proxy_fdpass_module (shared)
 proxy_ftp_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 proxy_scgi_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 systemd_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 evasive20_module (shared)
```

Output of `apachectl -M` above. Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: what does the log show for the 403?

Comment: This one: `client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/site/script.php`

Comment: that appears to be the error message you get in the browser.  what does the apache error log show?

Comment: It's directly from the error.log. Full line: `[Thu Nov 20 21:43:25.037497 2014] [:error] [pid 10732] [client ip] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/site/script.php`

Comment: @Mellnik, have you figured this out ? I have got exactly the same issue (just on Debian 7, apache 2.2.2), thanks

Comment: @dav Unfortunately not, I still get this very often on two of sites. One if them is vBulletin4 and Mediawiki. Maybe there is some shaky php function causing this.

Comment: @Mellnik, thanks for your reply, in fact, I made some more search and tried to find the solution, I have found smth, but not sure if this is the cause. will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 9):

I was having this exact problem, I am not sure if the below reason is what always causes this error(specifically in the described in the question way) but this was the case for me, so I just wanted to share my thoughts.

Debian 7 wheezy (7.7), apache 2.2.2

I was making a feature when the user should change the messages' status as read/unread, while clicking on a "link", when ajax was being sent to server, so, while testing - quickly clicking on that link to see if it works fine(so it wont be 2 concurrent ajax requests) I got this error

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /messages on this server.
```

The strange part was that before that there were a few successful ajax requests with normal path including the domain name like `http://example.com/messages/changeStatus/11`. Which means the code was ok. But, on the other hand if I could just wait a few seconds and try again, it would work fine.

I had mod-security and mod-evasive installed, so after this error I found these last lines from `/var/log/apache2/modsec_audit.log` file.

```
--ba0f4035-E--
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /messages/changeStatus/24
on this server.</p>
</body></html>

--ba0f4035-H--
Apache-Error: [file "mod_evasive20.c"] [line 246] [level 3] client denied by server configuration: /home/user_name/www/example/messages, referer: http://example.com/messages
Stopwatch: 1421177262896100 4724 (- - -)
Stopwatch2: 1421177262896100 4724; combined=10, p1=0, p2=0, p3=2, p4=0, p5=7, sr=0, sw=1, l=0, gc=0
Response-Body-Transformed: Dechunked
Producer: ModSecurity for Apache/2.6.6 (http://www.modsecurity.org/).
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) PHP/5.4.36-0+deb7u1 mod_ssl/2.2.27 OpenSSL/1.0.1h

--ba0f4035-Z--
```

Doing some more search, as I found out the log's error in this article.
https://www.atomicorp.com/wiki/index.php/Mod_evasive

so, mod evasive is the reason, because the default params of it are too sensitive, mainly in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/mod-evasive.conf` file by default I had these options

```
<ifmodule mod_evasive20.c>
   DOSHashTableSize 3097
   DOSPageCount  2
   DOSSiteCount  50
   DOSPageInterval 1
   DOSSiteInterval  1
   DOSBlockingPeriod  10
   DOSLogDir   /var/log/mod_evasive
   DOSEmailNotify  EMAIL@DOMAIN.com
   DOSWhitelist   127.0.0.1
</ifmodule>
```

as we learn from the above link

> MODEV_DOSPageCount - This is the threshhold for the number of requests
>   for the same page (or URI) per page interval. Once the threshhold for
>   that interval has been exceeded, the IP address of the client will be
>   added to the blocking list.

and

> MODEV_DOSPageInterval - The interval for the page count threshhold;
>   defaults to 1 second intervals.

So, according to default options if I would do 2 requests for the same url during 1 second it would show 403 error, and it was smth that happened to me: ASA I increased the number to 20, I was unable already replicate the error message.

on other hand

> MODEV_DOSBlockingPeriod The blocking period is the amount of time (in
>   seconds) that a client will be blocked for if they are added to the
>   blocking list. During this time, all subsequent requests from the
>   client will result in a 403 (Forbidden) and the timer being reset
>   (e.g. another 10 seconds). Since the timer is reset for every
>   subsequent request, it is not necessary to have a long blocking
>   period; in the event of a DoS attack, this timer will keep getting
>   reset

so, as we can see, after `DOSBlockingPeriod` time has passed the ip will be deleted from blacklist; as I am guessing this is the reason, that there are no banned IPs in logs, also that, when clicking F5 after a few seconds it works fine, as the blocked period has passed.

I also tested this with long blocking period and small page count values, mainly setting 1000 and 1 respectively. and After a 2-3 ajax requests it started showing 403 and did not go away after a few seconds.

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: Thanks, I will complete disable evasive for a while and report back the results.

Answer (score 0):

Did you just upgrade to 2.4 from 2.2? Try [Upgrading to 2.4 from 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html).

Comment: No, running 2.4 from the beginning. It's the default version of CentOS 7.

Comment: Any reason why you downvoted my question alexius bobby?

Comment: @Mellnik What made you think it was me? I was actually trying to be helpful, so I format and tried to answer your question.

Comment: Sorry, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this same problem - except mod_evasive was not install. I am 100% sure it was not installed, or enabled.

The solution was to install libapache2-mod-evasive and then disable it. Maybe it's being merged into Apache core?

Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2017-07-27T14:34:01